# Document from firebase gets cut after some data

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried to retrieve document from firestore in my flutter application.
Below are screenshots of the data I am retrieving.
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the code I am using

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('schemes').doc("2VfjbKGY60ZE0HVz6dLz").get()
                              .then((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> documentSnapshot) {
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                              print(documentSnapshot.data());
                              //print(documentSnapshot.data()!['name ']);
                            }
                          });
```

I am getting output which looks like this:
[image]

I want to get the whole document from firebase and retrieve some fields from them. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('schemes').doc("2VfjbKGY60ZE0HVz6dLz").get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
     var title=doc['longDescriptions'];
     List benefits=doc['benefits'];
     //....rest of document fields
  }
});
```

You should include your statement in a **Future async/await** function and call it in **initState** function
or use it in a **FutureBuilder** widget if you want to listen to document only once or **StreamBuilder** widget for continous listening for anychanges.